# Как пишется "на( )руки"?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется наречие *на( )руки?* И как определить, писать слитно или раздельно наречия?

Comment: Я правильно вас понял?

Answer (score 2):

Я что-то не понял. Почему вы считаете, что *на руки* — наречие? Это слово с предлогом, а синтаксическая функция этого сочетания — обстоятельство: кинул (куда?) на руки, посмотри (на что?/куда?) на руки. В последнем примере, вероятно, это дополнение, которое по семантике схоже с обстоятельством.

Comment: Может быть и наречием. Даже скорее всего наречие - по грамматической функции в выражениях типа "получил на руки".

Comment: Но тут такая штука, что у автора стояло "на рук" - понимай как хочешь. Я решил, что вероятнее всего ближе к наречию именно этот оборот, и исправил по своему разумению.

Comment: >> *Может быть и наречием. Даже скорее всего наречие - по грамматической функции в выражениях типа "получил на руки"*    Часть речи может выражаться двумя словами?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Конечно, может. Вы не разу не сталкивались одним из самых запутанных разделов русской орфографии о слитном-раздельном написании наречий? Глагол в будущем времени. А числительное - хоть из миллиона. Вообще понятие "слова" само по себе далеко не всегда понимается как нечто слитно пишущееся даже с позиций общей грамматики. Другое дело, что в русском языке эти вещи часто смешивают именно в силу того что подобные примеры в процентном отношении довольно редки.

Answer (score 2):

> Как пишется наречие на()руки?

.

См. [***"Толковый словарь" Ефремовой:***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188887)

> **на́ руки**
>
> *нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*
>
> Лично (*вручать, отдавать, получать и т.п.*).

.

Наречием (в знач. "лично") ***на руки*** названо и в ***"Словаре наречий и служебных слов русского языка"*** Бурцевой:

> **На руки**, *нареч. разг.* Лично.
>
> *Не выдавайте ему зарплату на руки.*

.

И во многих других словарях...

Answer (score 1):

Выдавать на руки, сдать на руки, передать лично в руки - это, скорее, устойчивые выражения (падежные формы существительного имеют обстоятельственное значение, употребляются в значении наречия).

Также: взять себя в руки, держать себя в руках, это на руку (выгодно) кому-то и т.д. Во всех случаях раздельное написание.

И обычные  сочетания существительного и предлога: взять на руки, одеть на руки.

Вообще говоря, эта группа предложных сочетаний **интересна тем, что парные варианты "наречие - существительное" не разграничиваются (как обычно) по слитному и раздельному написанию** (сравнить: действовать наудачу - надеяться на удачу). Возможно, это связано с большим количеством различных форм, в  которых используется существительное "рука".

Answer (score 0):

По поводу раздельного написания наречия "на руки" у Д.Розенталя есть правило: "Раздельно пишутся наречия, образованные от существительных, употребляемых в переносном значении: крикнуть в сердцах, ему это на руку,  выдать зарплату на руки"